# What does the opcode EXT_STMT do in the Zend engine?

Tags: php, opcode

It seems that all PHP files, except for the empty file, have the opcode `EXT_STMT` scattered liberally through the compiled opcodes. For example:

```
$ cat << EOF > hello.php
> <?php
> echo 'Hello';
> ?>
> EOF

$ php -dvld.active=1 -dvld.execute=0 hello.php
Finding entry points
Branch analysis from position: 0
Return found
filename:       /home/james/dev/php/hello.php
function name:  (null)
number of ops:  4
compiled vars:  none
line     # *  op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   2     0  >   EXT_STMT                                                 
         1      ECHO                                                     'Hello'
   4     2      EXT_STMT                                                 
         3    > RETURN                                                   1

branch: #  0; line:     2-    4; sop:     0; eop:     3
path #1: 0,
```

What does this `EXT_STMT` do? [Its entry in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.ext-stmt.php) has pretty much no documentation.